# How do I set RowDefinition Height to a Dynamic Resource?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dynamicresource

I'm trying to use `DynamicResource` to set the height of rows in a grid but it is not working and I am unsure why. I've created a default Xamarin project in Visual Studio to test.

Here is the relevant page:

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestDynamicResource.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Orange">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{DynamicResource RowHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={DynamicResource RowHeight}, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Testing Color Change on this one" TextColor="{DynamicResource LabelColor}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Testing Height" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Testing Height Change on this one through binding"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the main `App` class:

```
  public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Resources.Add("TestConverter", new TestConverter());
            Resources["RowHeight"] = new GridLength(15);
            Resources["LabelColor"] = Color.Brown;

            InitializeComponent();


            MainPage = new MainPage();

            UpdateResources();
        }

        private async void UpdateResources()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wait 5 seconds");
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Change color to RED and height to 500");
            Resources["RowHeight"] = new GridLength(500);
            Resources["LabelColor"] = Color.Red;

            Console.WriteLine("Wait 5 seconds");
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Change color to BLUE and height to 25");
            Resources["RowHeight"] = new GridLength(25);
            Resources["LabelColor"] = Color.Blue;


            Console.WriteLine("Wait 5 seconds");
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Change color to DeepPink and height to 100");
            Resources["RowHeight"] = new GridLength(100);
            Resources["LabelColor"] = Color.DeepPink;


        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
```

And the converter being used:

TestConverter.cs

```
public class TestConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is DynamicResource dr)
            {
                if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(dr.Key))
                {

                    if (Application.Current.Resources[dr.Key] is GridLength gridLengthResult)
                        return gridLengthResult;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Resources do not contain: " + dr.Key);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Returning null");
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Here is a result of when the application is started:

[image: GIF of application]

As you can see, the height never changes.

I've tried this for colors, padding, corner radius of frames, and grid row definition height -- the height is the only one that doesn't work for me.

I've also gone and implemented a converter and tried setting the row height like so:

`<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={DynamicResource RowHeight}, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"/>`

But that only sets the height the first time, there are no subsequent changes.

Am I misunderstanding how binding and dynamic resources work?  Or is this a bug in Xamarin?

I've figured out workarounds for this issue but would like it to work as I have it in the question.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a "bug", but rather it is "a limitation, by design". `DynamicResource` is typically used for details that do not require "layout" to be called, to re-position elements on page. Try calling `Application.Current.MainPage.ForceLayout();` after the change.
`

Comment: That makes sense, I will try that and see what happens. Thanks @ToolmakerSteve!

Comment: Also, do you know if the design limitation is documented anywhere? I would like to read up on it in case I run across similar scenarios in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, `Application.Current.MainPage.ForceLayout();` did not do the trick. I added it after each line that updates the resources but nothing seems to happen. With the converter, it still takes the first value, without the converter it acts as if there is nothing.

Comment: You'll probably have to use `Binding` instead, as shown in Jessie Zhang's answer. No DynamicResource.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `RowDefinition`'s Height to a Dynamic value. You can do as follows:

1.created a view model `RowHeightClass`

```
public class RowHeightClass: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        bool swith;

        //public GridLength rowFirstHeight { set; get; }
        GridLength _rowFirstHeight;
        public GridLength RowFirstHeight
        {
            get => _rowFirstHeight;
            set => SetProperty(ref _rowFirstHeight, value);
        }


        //public GridLength rowSecondHeight { set; get; }
        GridLength _rowSecondHeight;
        public GridLength RowSecondHeight
        {
            get => _rowSecondHeight;
            set => SetProperty(ref _rowSecondHeight, value);
        }

        public RowHeightClass()
        {
            //initial RowFirstHeight and  RowSecondHeight
            RowFirstHeight = new GridLength(15);

            RowSecondHeight = new GridLength(15);
        }


        public ICommand ResetHeightCommand => new Command(resetHeight);

        private void resetHeight()
        { //reset RowFirstHeight and  RowSecondHeight
            if (!swith)
            {
                RowFirstHeight = new GridLength(50);
                RowSecondHeight = new GridLength(50);
            }
            else {
                RowFirstHeight = new GridLength(15);
                RowSecondHeight = new GridLength(15);
            }

            swith = !swith;
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.bind the properties in `MainPage.xaml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DynamicHeightApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Orange">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowFirstHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowSecondHeight}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Testing Color Change on this one" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Testing Height" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Testing Height Change on this one through binding"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button  Text="reset" Command="{Binding ResetHeightCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

3.MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    RowHeightClass rowHeightClass;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

         rowHeightClass = new RowHeightClass();

        BindingContext = rowHeightClass;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I added two properties `RowFirstHeight` and `RowSecondHeight` and implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for this view model, if we change the value of above properties, the UI will update automatically.

Comment: So `DynamicResource` doesn't actually work for these specific bindings?

Comment: In my project I am implementing this in I already have a view model that contains data for the view. The grid row heights are a separate set of data, so I was hoping to be able to update them the same as most other properties in XAML.

Comment: Yes, the `DynamicResource` is not suitable for adjusting the height or width for a layout.

Comment: You can try to add theses binding properties to your ViewModel. We generally put the data corresponding to a page in the same View model, which makes the code more brief and less confusing.